# Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CommonEntities.DTOModels>

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a .net MVC application to create API.

But it is showing the error in a method.

```
public IEnumerable<TicketStatusByBusinessCustomerDTOModel> 
    FetchAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomer()
{
    return GetAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomer();
}
```

here is my method below

```
public string GetAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomer()
{
    string returnStr = string.Empty;
    ObjectResult<string> queryResult = _ticketContext.sp_FetchAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomers();
    foreach (string result in queryResult)
    {
        returnStr = Convert.ToString(result);
    }
    return returnStr; 
}

public virtual ObjectResult<string> sp_FetchAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomers()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("sp_FetchAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomers");
}
```

I have tried several method but failed.
I'm actually new to mvc architecture.
can anyone please tell where did i do wrong?

Comment: Please do not paste images of code or data, only text. Please show a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: `public IEnumerable<string> FetchAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomer()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomer() returns a string object and your FetchAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomer() is a collection.

Comment: so can you please tell what to do?

Comment: @ArifRaihan we don't know what you exactly need but changing method declaration should help `public string 
FetchAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomer()`

Comment: FetchAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomer() returns a collection of data.
should i change the  GetAllTicketStatusByBusinessCustomer method?